# Unable to resolve NULL driver for [Illuminate\Session\SessionManager]

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, session-management, invalidargumentexception, laravel-session

I am using Laravel 5.7. My application is working fine last night. but suddenly this error appears. I did not change any file. Now I am searching for a solution but I did not find any. I am new on laravel I am not familiar with core files of Laravel.
please check the error in the attached image.

here is .env session portion

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

And this is env file code
[image]

[image]
I dont have any file session.php file in config

[image]

Comment: Can you also copy and paste the contents of your `config/session.php` file to your question.

Comment: i dont have any session.php file in config

Comment: Ah ha, you should do. Has it been accidentally deleted?

Comment: Dear, I did not delete any files. but as you are saying i think i missed it. let me search for the file online and then placed it.

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/laravel/5.7/config/session.php

Comment: Thank you so much, dear. my issue is resolved. the file was missing I added again and now it is working. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going of the conversation in the comments, the issue is that you don't have a `session.php` inside your `config` directory. The reason this is an issue is because Laravel will use that config file to get the name of the session driver and, like all config values, if it isn't present it will just return `null`.

Adding [the default session config file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/laravel/5.7/config/session.php) to that directory should solve your issue.